# traversing json object with unknown property using JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON object and using JS/jquery I am trying to list all boom entries that have a count greater than 0

using the following JS I can access all the boom's, but as the next property is unknown, how can I access the count?

**id_unknown** is not known in the example, as in, I don't know what the property name is so I can't do jsonData["foo"]["id"]["bar"]["id_unknown"]; I need to step over it almost and access everything inside it

```
obj = JSON.parse(results);
var prod = obj['foo'][id]['bar'];

     $.each(prod, function(i) {
               $.each(prod[i], function(boom) {
               console.log(boom);                  
            });
         });
```

JSON :

```
"foo":{  
  "id":{  
     "bar":{  
        "id_unknown":{  
           "boom":{  
              "count":9.0
           },
           "boom2":{  
              "count":48.0
           },
           "boom4":{  
              "count":103.0
           },
           "boom5":{  
              "count":0.0
          }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
var jsonData = {
    "foo": {
        "id": {
            "bar": {
                "id_unknown": {
                    "boom": {
                        "count": 9.0
                    },
                        "boom2": {
                        "count": 48.0
                    },
                        "boom4": {
                        "count": 103.0
                    },
                        "boom5": {
                        "count": 0.0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
var data = jsonData["foo"]["id"]["bar"];
var unknownProperties = [];
$.each(data, function (k, e) {
    $.each(data[k], function (key, element) {
        alert(element["count"]);
    });
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: **id_unknown** is not known in the example, as in, I don't know what the property name is so I can't do jsonData["foo"]["id"]["bar"]["id_unknown"];

I need to step over it almost and access everything inside it

Comment: I updated as your requirement. I run 2 each loops.